# Compressing an int[]

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, compression

I want to write an int[][] consisting of integers from 0 to x(Where x is the number of images in a color). At the moment, I'm just writting a column element, then a seperator character, then an element, and repeat. Then once I finish my column, I write a column seperator and move to the next one.

```
for (int i = 0; i < imageColors.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < imageColors[0].length; j++) {
        writer.append(compressedColors[i][j]);
       writer.append("!");
    }
    writer.append("@");
}
```

I'm ok with writing my array column by column and seperating by `@`, but is there a better way I can write the columns? Especially considering a LOT of the elements are consecutive and identical, I feel like this could be done using a lot less file space. As long as I'm able to decode to the original data, anything goes.

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you just zip the result?

Comment: Zipping isn't an option for what I'm doing here

Comment: Is it OK to store it in binary? No strings involved?

Comment: Why not?  What *are* the constraints?

Comment: Base 36 would take up less file space then base 2 would it not? And I'm trying to write a file format that offers lossless quality and decent compression rates. I don't expect to rival PNG or something, but I need my raw file to be as small as possible. I can ZIP my final file, I can ZIP a PNG, but I still need the raw file as small as possible

Comment: I'm not suggesting using 0 and 1 characters, but actual binary data, as in, raw bytes

Comment: I've never worked with data like that, but if you could show some sort of example for how to compress an int array using that, I can figure out the 2d array and the decompression

Comment: Well, what sort of techniques would you like in there? Something Deflate-derived? (back-references in a sliding window, canonical Huffman encoding, but of course a larger alphabet) Something simpler? (what?) More different? (edit: unfortunately I have to leave for a couple of hours, I'll get back to this later)

Comment: Um, I didn't understand a single technique you just said :P I'm still learning the basics of data compression, so nothing ridiculously complex, just something effective? I don't really know

Comment: Perhaps you should read up on those, they're actually pretty simple (both in an absolute sense and relative to many compression techniques that aim to get even higher compression ratios). If you want to post questions about them, I'd be happy to answer (if I come across them anyway). They're both interesting (imo) and useful, you'll almost always get a much smaller file than just collapsing ranges, and of course using base 256 is an immediate big improvement too.

Answer (score 0):

Writing integers in hex makes them shorter, you just need to remember to use base 16 when reading them back.  Sometimes fixed length encoding can save space by cutting out the number separators, your "!".  This depends on how many leading zeros your numbers have.  Also, if all your numbers fit into a short or a byte then you can save space with a `short[][]` or a `byte[][]`.

As you say, the big one is probably run-length encoding.  Rather than:

```
"1234!1234!1234!1234!@"
```

you have something like:

```
"r4x1234!@"
```

Again, you will need to rewrite your reading code to take account.  The "r" signals that this is a run length, not a plain number.  The "x" separates the run length from the number that is to be repeated.

Short run lengths can lengthen the output; no compression method is perfect.  Use `"1234!5678!"` instead of `"r1x1234!r1x5678!"`

Here is some **untested** code for run length encoding.  I have set it to use hex and to reject runs shorter than three.

```
void writeArray(int[][] imageColors, Writer writer) throws IOException {
    for (int i = 0; i < imageColors.length; i++) {
        writer.append(processRow(imageColors[i]));
        writer.append("@");
    }

}

String processRow(int[] row) {
    int pointer = 0;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(DEFAULT_ROW_LENGTH);

    // Set up for first rum.
    int currentValue = row[pointer];
    int repeatCount = 1;
    pointer++;

    while (pointer < row.length) {
        if (row[pointer] == currentValue) {
            // One more value in this run.
            ++repeatCount;
            ++pointer;
        } else {
            // End of run.
            if (repeatCount == 1) {
                sb.append(Integer.toHexString(currentValue));
            } else if (repeatCount == 2) {
                sb.append(Integer.toHexString(currentValue));
                sb.append("!");
                sb.append(Integer.toHexString(currentValue));
            } else {
                // Process long run >= 3.
                sb.append("r"); // "r" for "run".
                sb.append(Integer.toHexString(repeatCount));
                sb.append("x"); // Separate run length from value.
                sb.append(Integer.toHexString(currentValue));
            }
            sb.append("!");

            // Set up for next run.
            currentValue = row[pointer];
            repeatCount = 1;
            pointer++;
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Just to keep you happy, there is an obvious piece of the code missing.  Including it would have complicated the example without adding anything new.  I leave that as an exercise for the reader.